# How to activate .insertBefore on screen width change?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this snippet which switches the position of the secondary wrapper above the primary wrapper if the screen width is below 767px. This works great however it only works on refresh. How do I get it to work automatically when the screen width is changed?

Thanks! Total novice here.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

if(screen.width<=767){

jQuery('body.single #secondary').insertBefore('#primary');
}

});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are using jquery so I would recommend the .resize() method.

https://api.jquery.com/resize/

This will fire whenever the window is resized. You can have it do whatever you need at that point.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    If (myWindow.width() >= windowThreshold){
        //do all the things...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
// do something with screen width
});
```

or with jQuery:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    // do something with screen width
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [.resize()](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) method because you are using JQuery. This method is called whenever the window is resized.

Now, you can add you code like this.

```js
var windowThreshold = 767;

$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < windowThreshold + 1) {
    // do something with $(window).width()
    $("#log").append("<div>The window size is " + $(window).width() + "px</div>");
    $('#secondary').insertBefore('#primary');
  }
});
```

```css
#primary {
  background-color: red;
}

#secondary {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="log"></div>
<div id="primary">primary</div>
<div id="secondary">secondary</div>
```

You also can use  `.on("resize", function() {})`

```js
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  if ($(window).width() < windowThreshold + 1) {
    // do something with $(window).width()
    $("#log").append("<div>The window size is " + $(window).width() + "px</div>");
    $('#secondary').insertBefore('#primary');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this has an accepted answer, but just for the record, you could let CSS do the work by using media queries and flexbox as well.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}
div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px; 
}
.box {
  background: tomato;
  order: 1;
}
.circle {
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: lightblue;
  order: 2;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .box {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```